# How to detect client locale in JSF application?

Tags: java, jsf, localization, internationalization

How can I use `ServletRequest.getLocale()` in JSF application, when `Servlet` is absent in my code and is provided by JSF implementation? I'm trying to use `ServletContextListener`, but is it possible to reach `ServletRequest` from `ServletContextEvent`?

Anyway, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestLocale();
```

?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way in my opinion is to provide the links on your home page for various locales your application needs to support. This is less intrusive for the end user. Otherwise the end user has to keep changing the locales browser specific way. Also different browsers send the locale different ways to the server which is also problematic depending on your usecase.

I strongly suggest you go through [this](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/i18n/i18n4.html) tutorial.

Comment: The link is now broken.